# Error with cin and string

Tags: c++, string, char

I am fairly new to C++ and I am having trouble understanding what is the difference between these two. When i try an input stream  like the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

string* str = new string[50];
cin >> str;
```

I get the following error:

Error: no operator ">>" matches these operands. operand types are: std:istream >> std:string*

However, when I try the following option with char, I don't have any issues.

```
char* str = new char[50];
```

Can someone please explain what the difference is between these two? I am not understanding why the string is giving an error.

Thanks

Comment: The difference is that one is a string array and the other is a char array.  Char arrays are C strings, but no overload for `std::string[]` is defined.  They're different types.

Comment: You probably simply meant to use `string str;`

Comment: You should explain what it is you're trying to do. (Do you not realize the first dynamically allocates an array of 50 strings? Or are you trying to create arrays of strings? Are you trying to do dynamic allocation specifically? Or do you not realize you have choices?) Why not just `string str; cin >> str;`?

Comment: you have defined an array of string...to initialize  a value to array of something(in you example string) you should use cin>>str[0]; and to 49.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I am trying to create one simple string and use the cin >> function to put what I want into it. It is now clear to me that I was creating an array of strings which is wrong however when I try the same thing you mentioned here with string str; cin >> str; I am getting this same error mentioned above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code:

```
string* str = new string[50];
```

This creates an array of 50 `string` objects. The `string` class encapsulates its own dynamically sized character array. You don't need to specify a length, the `string` class hides all that drudgery for you.

```
cin >> str;
```

This now fails because `cin` doesn't know how to handle an array of 50 strings. What I think you meant to do is simply create a new blank string with something like:

```
string str;
```

`cin` knows how to handle `string` objects. so you can use code like:

```
cin >> str;
```

One advantage of using `string`s this is that when `str` goes out of scope (the function exits) proper cleanup will be done. There is no need to do `delete str` as you would have had to do with your test code.

Regarding this code:

```
char* str = new char[50];
```

This creates a fixed size character array of size 50. `cin` knows how to handle a simple array of characters (`char *`) so has no problem handling it.

More information on the `string` class can be found at this [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/). The description given is:

> Strings are objects that represent sequences of characters.
>
> The standard string class provides support for such objects with an interface similar to that of a standard container of bytes, but adding features specifically designed to operate with strings of single-byte characters.

Comment: You should create a new string with `string str;`

Comment: Thanks that makes sense however I am still receiving that same error if I set it as just string str; Do I need to use the array of chars for cin or is there something i might be doing wrong still?

Comment: If you create a new program with proper includes and a `main()` that simply has `string str; cin >> str; cout << str;` in it - do you get an error? As well I assume after your includes you have `using namespace std;`?

Comment: Maybe you need `std::string str;` instead of `string str;`

Comment: @VinceAbruzzese : what compiler/development environment are you using? Visual C++ (Microsoft Windows) gcc? etc.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I am using Visual Studio 2013 C++. I have tried a new empty project and this worked fine. However I am using a client TCP Program that I am adding on to which does not work. It works for the char array but not the string

Comment: @MichaelPetch The code is a little long to provide but it is at this point that I am trying to use the string and it is giving an error. 'code'

  do {

   cout << "please enter the name of the 
   
   file = fopen(file_name, "r");

   if (file){
    cout << "We have a file";
   }
   else {
    cout << "We don't have a file with this name...\n\n";
   }

  } while (!file);
  //szbuffer[256]

  if (file_name == NULL){
   throw "File not found\n";
   exit(1);
  }

  cout << "please enter the type direction of transfer: ";
  
  string* type_direction;
  
  cin >> type_direction;

  locale 'code'

Comment: I think I see the issue. In the code you pasted you have this `string* type_direction`. You don't want to specify it as a pointer. Just create the string like this `string type_direction`

Comment: @MichaelPetch yes actually that was my issue. I was confusing it with the char array which does use a pointer. This makes sense now. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, in C, a string is basically an array of chars. C++ provides an easier way of doing it using "string".

The following page describes both types, with examples: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_strings.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
string* str = new string[50];
```

Is an array containing `string`s.

```
char* str = new char[50];
```

Is an array containing `char`s.

---

In C, a `char` array is the same as a `string`. So when you use `cin`, it needs to pass input to a `string` (or in your case, a `char` array).